# Copying a dataset with XMLA Endpoint in Power BI Endpoint returns null for the model

Tags: c#, powerbi, xmla

I am currently working on utilizing XMLA Endpoint with C# to copy a datamodel that exists in my workspace.

The steps I am following are:

1. Create the new datamodel with a dummy model
2. copy the current model over to the new datamodel.

- This is where I have issues.  When I connect to my existing datamodel in Visual Studios the value for model is 'null'.

Can someone direct me to how I can resolve this?  Or do I need to recreate the entire model in code other than copy it?

My goal is to have a template datamodel that I will copy to different workspaces and then modify them from there.

I have been working with the below code:

```
 
const string connectString = "powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/MYDATAMODEL";
 

static void Main(string[] args) {

    Server server = new Server();
    server.Connect(connectString);
    Model model = server.Databases[0].Model;

 

    string sourceDatabaseName = "DATABASE";
    string DatabaseName = "DATABASE - Copy";

    Database sourceDatabase = server.Databases.GetByName(sourceDatabaseName);

        string newDatabaseName = server.Databases.GetNewName(DatabaseName);
        Database targetDatabase = CreateDatabase(newDatabaseName);
        sourceDatabase.Model.CopyTo(targetDatabase.Model);
        targetDatabase.Model.SaveChanges();

        targetDatabase.Model.RequestRefresh(RefreshType.Full);
        targetDatabase.Model.SaveChanges();

     
     Database CreateDatabase(string DatabaseName)
    {

        string newDatabaseName = server.Databases.GetNewName(DatabaseName);

        var database = new Database()
        {
            Name = newDatabaseName,
            ID = newDatabaseName,
            CompatibilityLevel = 1520,  
            StorageEngineUsed = Microsoft.AnalysisServices.StorageEngineUsed.TabularMetadata,
            Model = new Model()
            {
                Name = DatabaseName + "-Model",
                Description = "A Demo Tabular data model with 1520 compatibility level."
            }
        };

        server.Databases.Add(database);
        database.Update(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.UpdateOptions.ExpandFull);

        return database;
    }

}
```

[image]